Why won't these IK bones rotate?
I'm trying to be able to bend this 1/4" thick sheet metal from flat to 90 degrees using an IK rig, but the IK constraint sub-target named "last_IK" (cone shape in pose mode) barely seems to barely effect the angle on each of the small bones that make up the bend portion of the sheet metal. Can anyone shed some light on what might be the problem? Thanks for your help.
Blender file link:
Blender file
Edit mode setup: IK constraint sub-target named "last_IK" is circled in red, the yellow bone named last.001 has the IK constraint.

Pose mode setup with last_IK in one position circled in red:

Pose mode setup with last_IK in another position circled in red


can u pls provide blend file because rigging isn't that simple...

hi @Chris I've added the file link above. Thanks for any help!

please watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=suP14lYWpN8 to understand how pole targets work

ah great thanks @Chris for the video reference I'll follow back once I get to watch it

Hi @chris where should I be placing a pole target bone since I have more than just a knee/elbow joint? Thanks
